# Sort List according to more than only constraint in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, scala-collections

I am desperately trying to find a way to sort a List of strings, where the strings are predefined identifiers of following form: a1.1, a1.2,..., a1.100, a2.1, a2.2,....,a2.100,...,b1.1, b1.2,.. and so on, which is alread the correct ordering. So each identifier is first ordered by its first character (descending alphabetic order) and within this ordering descending ordered by consecutive numbers. I have tried sortWith by providing a sorting function specifying the above rule for all two consecutive list members.

```
scala> List("a1.102", "b2.2", "b2.1", "a1.1").sortWith((a: String, b: String) => a.take(1) < b.take(1) && a.drop(1).toDouble < b.drop(1).toDouble)
res2: List[java.lang.String] = List(a1.102, a1.1, b2.2, b2.1)
```

This is not the ordering I expected. However, by swapping the ordering of the expressions, as

```
scala> List("a1.102", "b2.2", "b2.1", "a1.1").sortWith((a: String, b: String) => (a.drop(1).toDouble < b.drop(1).toDouble && a.take(1) < b.take(2)))
res3: List[java.lang.String] = List(a1.1, a1.102, b2.1, b2.2)
```

this indeed gives me (at least for this example) the desired ordering, which I do not understand neither.

I would be so thankful, if somebody could give me a hint what exactly is going on there and how I can sort lists as I wish (with a more complex boolean expression than only comparing < or >). A further question: The strings I am sorting (in my example) are actually keys from a HashMap m. Will any solution effect sorting m by its keys within

```
m.toSeq.sortWith((a: (String, String), b: (String, String)) => a._1.drop(1).toDouble < b._1.drop(1).toDouble && a._1.take(1) < b._1.take(1))
```

Many thanks in advanced!

Comment: Thank you so much everybody! I am new to programming in Scala, but I enjoy it so incredibly much! But I still run myself into some serious headaches, with things like these ;) I assumed, I would get back a list, for which each two consecutive elements match my constraint. I have accepted the second answer, because everything i s clear to me now. As every answer really helped me learn more, but I am new to this board, please just let me know, how i could grant those helpful answers too, if needed! Thank you for everybodys friendlyness :) Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: I misread your example—you want `a1.2` to precede `a1.102`, which the `toDouble` versions below won't get right. I'd suggest the following instead:

```
items.sortBy { s =>
  val Array(x, y) = s.tail.split('.')
  (s.head, x.toInt, y.toInt)
}
```

Here we use Scala's `Ordering` instance for `Tuple3[Char, Int, Int]`.

---

It looks like you have a typo in your second ("correct") version: `b.take(2)` should doesn't make sense, and should be `b.take(1)` to match the first. Once you fix that, you get the same (incorrect) ordering.

The real problem is that you only need the second condition in the case where the numbers match. So the following works as desired:

```
val items = List("a1.102", "b2.2", "b2.1", "a1.1")
items.sortWith((a, b) =>
  a.head < b.head || (a.head == b.head && a.tail.toDouble < b.tail.toDouble)
)
```

I'd actually suggest the following, though:

```
items.sortBy(s => s.head -> s.tail.toDouble)
```

Here we take advantage of the fact that Scala provides an appropriate `Ordering` instance for `Tuple2[Char, Double]`, so we can just provide a transformation function that turns your items into that type.

And to answer your last question: yes, either of these approaches should work just fine with your `Map` example.

Answer (score 0):

So consider what happens when your sorting function is passed `a="a1.1"` and `b="a1.102"`.
What you'd like is for the function to return true.  However, `a.take(1) < b.take(1)` returns false, so the function returns false.

Think about your cases a bit more carefully

- if the prefix is equal, and the tails are ordered properly, then the arguments are ordered properly
- if the prefixes are not equal, then the arguments are ordered properly only if the prefixes are.

So try this instead:

```
(a: String, b: String) => if (a.take(1) == b.take(1)) a.drop(1).toDouble < b.drop(1).toDouble else a.take(1) < b.take(1)
```

And that returns the proper ordering:

```
scala> List("a1.102", "b2.2", "b2.1", "a1.1").sortWith((a: String, b: String) => if (a.take(1) == b.take(1)) a.drop(1).toDouble < b.drop(1).toDouble else a.take(1) < b.take(1))
res8: List[java.lang.String] = List(a1.1, a1.102, b2.1, b2.2)
```

The reason it worked for you with the reversed ordering was luck.  Consider the extra input `"c0"` to see what was happening:

```
scala> List("c0", "a1.102", "b2.2", "b2.1", "a1.1").sortWith((a: String, b: String) => (a.drop(1).toDouble < b.drop(1).toDouble && a.take(1) < b.take(2)))
res1: List[java.lang.String] = List(c0, a1.1, a1.102, b2.1, b2.2)
```

The reversed function sorts on the numeric part of the string first, then on the prefix.  It just so happens that your numeric ordering you gave also preserved the prefix ordering, but that won't always be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a tuple containing the string before the `"."` and then the integer after the `"."`. This will use a lexicographic order for the first part and an order on the integer for the second part.

```
scala> val order = Ordering.by((s:String) => (s.split("\\.")(0),s.split("\\.")(1).toInt))
order: scala.math.Ordering[String] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$7@384eb259

scala> res2
res8: List[java.lang.String] = List(a1.5, a2.2, b1.11, b1.8, a1.10)


scala> res2.sorted(order)
res7: List[java.lang.String] = List(a1.5, a1.10, a2.2, b1.8, b1.11)
```

Comment: It's ok if the prefix only goes up to a2, but if it goes to a10 or higher, lexicographical order will stop working, so probably safer to do it as Travis did